# Purging RAWs in Aperture 3

Tags: raw, apple-aperture

I shoot RAW, and after importing and post-processing them in Aperture 3, I never need the RAW file again. This eats roughly 4-5x more disk space than if I had shot JPGs.

Is there an easy way to convert the processed RAWs to JPG and to purge the RAWs? Note that I do not have RAW+JPG pairs, only RAW.

The workflow that I thought of, is to export them to JPG in the highest quality setting, delete the RAWs, and then (re-)import the JPGs to replace the RAWs. But there must be something better. What is your workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program made for this called [RawHide for Aperture](http://ssoftltd.com/RawHide-Aperture).  I have used it myself to convert albums full of low-importance pictures from RAW to JPEG.  You can have it delete the originals automatically and replace them with JPEGs, or keep both; you can tag pictures you've operated on; and there are quite a few more options.